# Is there design pattern for showing same view controller in several places with some customization?

Tags: objective-c, ios, design-patterns

Very frequently we reuse same view controllers when developing universal apps both for iPhone and iPad. But frequently some customization is needed, like:

```
IF iPad THEN 
  ...
ELSE
  ...
```

So, in order to achieve such customization the controller might have some property that is set during initialization of the controller, or there might be custom constructors. Just curious is there design pattern that suites for such situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't.... :) Use a common class called for instance `MyClass` and then sub-class it `MyClass-iPad` & `MyClass-iPhone` and use two different XIB for each. Avoid using this kind of stuff (there is no need for it).

Explanation:

The iPad version should only be aware of classes of the type `Something-iPad` this makes the code clean and creates a well defined architecture. If I jump into your code and someone tell's me: "Ok Jacky Boy, you have to make changes on the iPad version". I won't care to look ath the `Something-iPhone` classes. Most of the logic (business) should be on super class `Something` where the small tweaks should be on the sub-classes.

On side note, on most of my projects, normally I don't have anything on the `Something-iPhone` classes, because the design is done on the XIB. On the `Something-iPad` I would normally keep a reference to a `UIPopOverController` (just an example) and some rotations tweaks.

**Edit 1:**

I would receive an `NSDictionary` on the init of the `UIViewController`, like this:

```
initWithNibName:bundle:configurationDictionary:
```

After receiving this configurationDictionary, I would then use it on the `viewDidLoad` (for example). You could then do some cool stuff like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[[self configurationDictionary] objectForKey:BACKGROUND_COLOR_KEY]];
}
```

Comment: What about customizing the same view controller for showing at different places? For example, I need to pop some view controller in full screen with custom background in one place, and to show the same controller in centered window with transparent background in other place.

Comment: Yep, thats looks cool. Just wondering is there any design pattern for this, other than factory pattern

Answer (score 1):

If you have different initializers or larger chunks of different functionality then it makes sense to define a base class with the core functionality and then an iPad-specific subclass and an iPhone-specific subclass.

But in cases where you only have a trivial difference (for example, displaying an action sheet), then I would simply use something like:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    // a bunch of stuff that is the same

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        // one or two lines for iPad
    } else {
        // one or two lines for iPhone
    }
}
```

I have plenty of situations where I do both - subclass for the bigger differences and use `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` for trivial differences in the base class.

Comment: Agreed. @Jacky Boy is right about having separate subclasses for iPad and iPhone, however there's a temptation just to use UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM for trivial differences - as you said :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need the same VC in N places but each time initialized a little differently I would move the logic in a specific **factory class / category** on the VC

like its done with **for example** SLRequest objects / in ShareKit